# Fade in elements when scroll down - but still showing on load

Tags: jquery, squarespace

I have the follow script for two elements on a website I'm putting together in Squarespace. It works great, but the two elements still show when I load the page. They disappear as soon as I start scrolling and then reappear at the right scroll depth.

Also, since I'm not very familiar with scripting, is there a way to combine the two together a bit more elegantly?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fades in the side nav when you scroll down -->
<script>
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600) {
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1598446896960_13951').fadeIn();
  }
  else {
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1598446896960_13951').fadeOut();
  }
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600) {
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1598448609497_14674').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1598448609497_14674').fadeOut();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hide in the HTML as you build it to remove the FOUC `<div id='block-yui...' style='display:none;'..`

Comment: To combine them use `,` in your selector: change `$('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1598446896960_13951').fadeIn();` to `$('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1598446896960_13951,#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1598448609497_14674').fadeIn();` - or better, add a class to all those you want to fade/in out then you don't need to change your script when you add another one (or rename/gets renamed automatically by the state of that id)

Comment: Thanks folks! I've got the following code input and it works perfectly:

<style>
  #lefty,#righty { display:none; }
</style>
<script>
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600) {
    $('#lefty,#righty').fadeIn();
  }
  else {
    $('#lefty,#righty').fadeOut();
  }
});
</script>